# Merging into select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selectfield and some radiobuttons. This select field contains years. These years should dynamically change while swiching between radio buttons.
For example if user click radio-button1 year range 1999 till 2013 dropdown will be shown.
While clicking radio-button2 same dropdown should contains yeras 1987 - 2013.
Do I need to delete all options and draw it from scratch? Or is there any trick, which allows to merge missing years(add the missing years or remove the unneeded ones)?

Comment: You can use `.prepend()` and `.append()` or `.before()` and `.after()` to insert the missing years, but redrawing it from scratch is probably easier and just as good.

Comment: Actually, all the missing years are at the beginning. Using `.before()` should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delete all an create new options in the select field. I think it's faster than searching for missing options and delete/insert them at the right position.